# Today's message from YouTube: Final Turndown Notice for YouTube Data API v2

Tags: api, youtube

Today, many YouTube developers received a message from Google telling them the following: 
As of April 20, 2015, v2 API endpoints will be shut off. However, YouTube will keep the v2 versions of some features, like video uploading, comments, captions, flagging features accessible for a grace period past the shutdown date.

Also, they asked developers to test their application's reaction to the v2 API shutdown, point it to eol.gdata.youtube.com instead of gdata.youtube.com.

I just changed my API to "eol.gdata.youtube.com" instead of "gdata.youtube.com" and it works fine. 
My question is: As long as direct video uploading to YouTube is no longer supported in API v3, does it mean Direct Video Uploading will be not available in v3?
More about migration your application at
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide